# How to check values within array of dictionaries without having a key in one line

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have an array like `[[URL: String]]` in which I save a random string as value for each `URL` which is a key in my dictionary. Therefore each key is different.

I am creating a random string and want to check whether this random string is already in the array or not. For this I am doing:

```
let randomString = self.randomString()

for obj in randomStringArray {
    for (key, value) in obj {
        if value != randomString {
            print("not found")
        }
    }    
}
```

**My question is:** Can I write it in one line using functions of array like `.filter`, `.contains` or `.first` etc.?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?  There is no particularly efficient way of doing this; You have to search all of the keys of all of the dictionaries in the array each time.  It would be better to use an algorithm for your `randomString` that guaranteed uniqueness.

Comment: @Paulw11 can you help me with the logic where i can get a perfectly unique random string of length 16. Right now I am using this code:

```let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
        let len = UInt32(letters.length)
        

        var randomString = ""
        
        for _ in 0 ..< 16 {
            let rand = arc4random_uniform(len)
            var nextChar = letters.character(at: Int(rand))
            randomString += NSString(characters: &nextChar, length: 1) as String
        }```

Comment: Does it have to be 16 characters?  a `UUID` would be the typical solution, but it is longer than that.  Even an MD5 hash of a UUID is 32 characters.

Comment: @Paulw11 no it does not need to be 16 char. Also I want to a new random string for every new URL fired by a user. So I don't understand how `UUID` would be useful

Comment: `UUID().uuidString` will give you a string version of the new uuid and uuids are unique for all intents and purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check whether any of the keyvalue pair in the array contains the value `randomstring` using `contains` like

```
  randomStringArray.contains(where:{$0.contains(where:{$1==randomString})})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `contains`:

```
if !obj.values.contains(randomString) {
    print("not found")      
}
```